# R - conditional incrementation

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

This should be trivial to code but could not think of an elegant one-liner in R. I have a dataframe as below:

```
data <- data.frame( index= seq(1:20), event=rep(0,20)   )
data$event[10] <- 1
data$event[15] <- 1
```

I simply want to add `start` and `stop` counter columns that increment in 10's and reset right after an `event=1` is observed. So the desired output with these two additional columns would be:

```
  index event start stop
1   1    0     0    10
2   2    0    10    20
3   3    0    20    30
4   4    0    30    40
5   5    0    40    50
6   6    0    50    60
7   7    0    60    70
8   8    0    70    80
9   9    0    80    90
10  10   1    90    100
11  11   0    0     10
12  12   0    10    20
13  13   0    20    30
14  14   0    30    40
15  15   1    40    50
16  16   0    0     10
17  17   0    10    20
18  18   0    20    30
19  19   0    30    40
20  20   0    40    50
```

Obviously, `data$stop <- data$start + 10` but how can I `apply()` the `start` incrementation loigc as described?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this:

```
Reduce(function(x,y) (1-y)*(x+10), data$event[-nrow(data)], accumulate=T, init=0)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could get your values with

```
data$start <- 10*(ave(
    rep(0,nrow(data)), 
    cumsum(c(0, head(data$event,-1))), 
    FUN=seq_along)-1
)
data$end <- data$start + 10
```

Here we use `cumsum` to track when events occur (but we need to shift them a step so the reset occurs after the event rather than at the event). And we use `ave` within the groups to generate sequences per group.

Answer (score 2):

So unfortunately, the apply family of functions only replaces a for loop when the iterations of that loop do not depend on previous iterations.

You could write a for loop like:

```
data <- data.frame( index= seq(1:20), event=rep(0,20)   )
data$event[10] <- 1
data$event[15] <- 1
print(data)
data$start = rep(0, 20)
for(i in 2:20){
  if(data$event[i] == 1){
    data$start[i] = 0
  } else  data$start[i] = data$start[i-1] + 10
}
data$stop = data$start+10
print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you @jarfa. However I suspect this is going to be a rather slow one. (although it caters for multiple conditions as well). I should have made it clear that I am trying to avoid for loops for performance reasons.

Comment: Ya, I figured you'd prefer not to use a for loop but I didn't know there was an alternative. The Reduce() function is pretty cool.