# Incrementation with multiple conditions

Tags: r

This question is an add-on to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156082/r-conditional-incrementation) one. I thought the additional condition was substantial enough to create a new question.

I have a dataframe of `date`s and `event`s as below.

```
data <- data.frame( date= as.Date(c(rep("24.07.2012",12), rep("25.07.2012",8)), format="%d.%m.%Y"), 
                    event=rep(0,20)   )
data$event[10] <- 1
data$event[15] <- 1
```

I want to add a `start` counter column that increments in 10's and reset:

- **1)** right after an event=1 is observed.
- **2)** when the date has changed from the previous row.

So the desired output with this additional `start` column would be:

```
         date   event start
1  2012-07-24     0     0
2  2012-07-24     0    10
3  2012-07-24     0    20
4  2012-07-24     0    30
5  2012-07-24     0    40
6  2012-07-24     0    50
7  2012-07-24     0    60
8  2012-07-24     0    70
9  2012-07-24     0    80
10 2012-07-24     1    90
11 2012-07-24     0     0
12 2012-07-24     0    10
13 2012-07-25     0     0
14 2012-07-25     0    10
15 2012-07-25     1    20
16 2012-07-25     0     0
17 2012-07-25     0    10
18 2012-07-25     0    20
19 2012-07-25     0    30
20 2012-07-25     0    40
```

The [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156082/r-conditional-incrementation) has very good solutions that only cater for condition **1**.

With the addition of condition 2, we now need to keep track of the `date` value for the `(n-1)th` row. So I am guessing this complicates the solution.

Any ideas to tackle this without a `for` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[, start := 10 * (seq_along(event) - 1), 
     by=list(date, cumsum(c(1L, diff(event) == -1L)))]
#turn the data.table into a data.frame:
class(data) <- "data.frame"
```

As @David Arenburg reminds me, there is `setDF` now that does essentially the same and some additional clean-up.

```
data
#         date event start
#1  2012-07-24     0     0
#2  2012-07-24     0    10
#3  2012-07-24     0    20
#4  2012-07-24     0    30
#5  2012-07-24     0    40
#6  2012-07-24     0    50
#7  2012-07-24     0    60
#8  2012-07-24     0    70
#9  2012-07-24     0    80
#10 2012-07-24     1    90
#11 2012-07-24     0     0
#12 2012-07-24     0    10
#13 2012-07-25     0     0
#14 2012-07-25     0    10
#15 2012-07-25     1    20
#16 2012-07-25     0     0
#17 2012-07-25     0    10
#18 2012-07-25     0    20
#19 2012-07-25     0    30
#20 2012-07-25     0    40
```

Comment: Thank you @Roland. At the end of the operation `class(data) [1] "data.table" "data.frame"`, can I continue treating `data` as a dataframe after this operation or do I need to `as.data.frame()`. The reason I am asking is `data` in reality is approx `5M rows *69cols` so would the conversion back and forth to data.table (if necessary) cause performance issues? (I am not familiar with the package)

Comment: I've edited my answer. However, with your data size you should work with data.tables.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will read more on the `data.table` package.

Comment: Using `class(data) <- "data.frame"` is interesting, it basically a short version of `setDF`

Answer (score 0):

For reference, this is the ugly `for` loop answer, that I want to avoid:

```
# for loop solution
data$start_loop <- rep (0, nrow(data))
for (r in 2:nrow(data)) {
  if( (data$event[r-1] == 1) | (data$date[r] != data$date[r-1] ) ){
    data$start_loop[r] = 0
  }
  else {
    data$start_loop[r] <- data$start_loop[r-1] + 10
  }
}
```